# log4j logging with different modules

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In my app, I have module B which depends on module A.

This is my module A log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, MODULEA

log4j.appender.MODULEA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MODULEA.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.MODULEA.File=/logs/moduleA.log
log4j.appender.MODULEA.MaxFileSize=40MB
log4j.appender.MODULEA.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.MODULEA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MODULEA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

moduleA pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp.mymoduleA</groupId>
<artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

And this is my Module B log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, MODULEB
log4j.appender.MODULEB=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.MODULEB.File=/logs/moduleB.log
log4j.appender.MODULEB.Append=true
log4j.appender.MODULEB.Threshold=ALL
log4j.appender.MODULEB.maxFileSize=40MB
log4j.appender.MODULEB.maxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.MODULEB.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MODULEB.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

moduleB pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>1.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp.mymoduleB</groupId>
<artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

When I build the war file for module B, I can see that module A is being used as a dependency. So no problem.
However, when I run the application, all logs from moduleA goes into /logs/moduleB.log.

Is there a way to override this so that moduleA will write to /logs/moduleA.log, or at least to a different file than moduleB.log

Comment: did you try to put those properties into one file only ? I mean merge log4j properties from 2 modules and provide the result.

Comment: I listed every module used by moduleA and put those modules/packages into the log4j.properties file of moduleB as log4j.category. It was a manual process. For example, moduleA uses moduleC and moduleD. in log4j.properties for moduleB, I did:
```-log4j.category.moduleA = debug, someappender
-log4j.category.moduleC = debug, someappender
-log4j.category.moduleD = debug, someappender
-log4j.additivity.moduleA(also C and D) = false (so that their outputs will not be visible in log file used by moduleB```